# Syntax error: Bad fd number?

Tags: shell-script, terminal, wine

My application:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# D2GS
#

# Go to the directory
cd ~

# Run the applications
if ! ps aux | pgrep "D2GS"; then
    wine "C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe" >& /dev/null &
fi
```

Gives error:

> ./d2gs.sh: 14: ./d2gs.sh: Syntax error: Bad fd number

Which is strange, since when I start `wine "C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe" >& /dev/null &` - it runs without any issues. The reason why I want to start it from shell is, because I want to crontab it every minute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`>&` is not syntax supported by `sh`.  You're explicitly using `sh` as the shell in that script.  You need to rewrite that line as:

```
wine "C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: It's only supported in <almost> every shell.  But it's not technically part of the posix shell spec.

Comment: Actually I had it confused for &>

Answer (score 9):

`>&` is the **csh** syntax (also supported by `zsh` and recent versions of `bash`) to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file.

In `sh` (Bourne (where it comes from) and POSIX), the redirection syntax¹ is:

```
if ! pgrep D2GS > /dev/null; then 
  wine C:/D2GS/D2GS.exe > /dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

(you've got the wrong ps/pgrep syntax as well; `pgrep` doesn't read its stdin, so piping the output of `ps` to it is pointless).

For completeness, the syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr in various shells:

- `> file 2>&1`: Bourne, POSIX and derivatives and fish
- `>& file`: csh, tcsh, zsh and bash 4+ (though in `zsh` and `bash` only when the file name is not a sequence of decimal digits, otherwise it's the `>&fd` Bourne redirection operator).
- `&> file`: bash and zsh 3+
- `> file >[2=1]`: rc and derivatives
- `> file ^&1`: fish

---

<sup>¹ `!` itself was introduced by the Korn shell and not available in the Bourne shell, though has been specified for `sh` by POSIX so should be available in any modern `sh` implementation.</sup>